# Is it possible to call unmanaged code using C# reflection from managed code?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, unmanaged, managed

Is it possible using reflection and C# .NET to call dynamically different function (with arguments) written in C or C++ before .NET came (unmanaged code) ?

A small C# example if possible would be appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, dynamic P/Invoke is possible in .NET in different ways.

#### LoadLibrary and Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer

Here's an example using `Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer` taken from the section *Delegates and unmanaged function pointers* from the article [*Writing C# 2.0 Unsafe Code*](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/PatrickSmacchia/CSharp2UnsafeCode02162006063859AM/CSharp2UnsafeCode.aspx) by Patrick Smacchia, a very similar sample is also available in this old [blog post by Junfeng Zhang](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/junfeng/dynamic-pinvoke)

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
class Program
{
     internal delegate bool DelegBeep(uint iFreq, uint iDuration);
     [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
     internal static extern IntPtr LoadLibrary(String dllname);
     [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
     internal static extern IntPtr GetProcAddress(IntPtr hModule,String procName);
     static void Main()
     {
          IntPtr kernel32 = LoadLibrary( "Kernel32.dll" );
          IntPtr procBeep = GetProcAddress( kernel32, "Beep" );
          DelegBeep delegBeep = Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer(procBeep , typeof( DelegBeep ) ) as DelegBeep;
          delegBeep(100,100);
     }
}
```

#### Reflection.Emit

This method work in all versions of .NET. It is described with an example in the documentation of [`System.Reflection.Emit.ModuleBuilder.DefinePInvokeMethod`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.emit.modulebuilder.definepinvokemethod)

Comment: Thanks for fast answer! 
Your described method for calling unmanaged function residing in ".dll". Does the same method holds for calling methods residing in ".exe" and ".lib" ?

Answer (score 2):

Reflection only works with managed code.

Depending on what the unmanaged code actually is you could use COM interop (for com components) or PInvoke (for old-style dll's) to invoke the unmanaged code. Maybe you can write a wrapper around the unmanaged code to make this possible.

Comment: This is not a 100% correct. Reflection (in the general sense as described in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_%28computer_science%29) is not limited to managed code.

Comment: Writting around wrapper is excluded because first one does not have code and second, if it goes without wrapping ...one should not wrapp :)